# Openssl: SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto() return failure

Tags: c, openssl

At the moment my openssl version is

OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

I use an example code offered by openssl [Simple_TLS_Server](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Simple_TLS_Server) to start a server and use s_client to send tls handshake. The server returned error like this:

```
139629255337616:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher:s3_srvr.c:1349
```

And the s_client returned:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140266915485328:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1471879558
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

After reading this [Manual:SSL_CTX_set1_curves(3)](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_CTX_set1_curves(3)), i modified some lines of the original:

```
if(!SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1)\n");
}
```

When i restarted the Simple_TLS_Server, it prints

```
Error: SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1)
```

Also tried like this:

```
if(!SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1))
{
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
}
```

But there was no available error message.
Does anyone know how could this happen? If you require more information, please just let me know.

PS: i tried certificates and keys with s_server and s_client, that worked fine.

Comment: *"... my openssl version is OpenSSL 1.0.2h 3 May 2016"* - Are you certain? Run `ldd` against your server and see which version of OpenSSL it is runtime link/loading. If its *not* the one you think, then either (1) build your server with `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib`; or (2) start your server with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib`.

Comment: @jww, thank you so much. I linked the server to the old version of OpenSSL library. Now i rebuild the server with `gcc -o test test.c -L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -I/usr/local/ssl/include -lssl -lcrypto -ldl`. The server works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how could this happen?

According to the source code the only cases where SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto return 0 is  when the openssl library was compiled without support for ECDH (OPENSSL_NO_ECDH) or without support for elliptic curves at all (OPENSSL_NO_EC).

Comment: I used the default configuration of OpenSSL, when i did ./config. My problem is like jww described above. Thanks.